# Would the Fidelius charm prevent me from shopping online?

Tags: harry-potter, fidelius-charm

The Fidelius charm is commonly used to hide the fact that certain people are hiding in a certain location. To achieve this, they entrust the knowledge of their location to a 'secret keeper' - this person is the only one capable of divulging the secret.

If, then, I've hidden that I am resident in Godric's Hollow with the Fidelius charm, and appointed an animagus friend of my mine as secret keeper, am I prevented from sharing that knowledge myself? Would I be incapable of ordering things from amazon, as that would involve handing out my name and address?

Comment: If you are a wizard, electronics are going to have a hard time functioning around you to begin with...

Comment: @Skooba, only around Hogwarts due to the unusually high concentration of magic in a relatively small area. A lone wizard in his house probably isn't surrounded by enough magic to prevent his smartphone working. Having said that, being under the effects of a Fidelius charm might cause that kind of interference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Harry Potter wiki on the [Fidelius Charm](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Fidelius_Charm):

> Once the secret has been implanted, the only method for another to learn it is for the primary Secret Keeper to divulge it to that person directly, it cannot be discovered any other way.

And explained by Professor Flitwick in *Prisoner of Azkaban*:

> As long as the Secret Keeper refused to speak, You-Know-Who could search the village where Lily and James were staying for years and never find them, not even if he had his nose pressed against their sitting room window!

If that secret happens to be your exact address, then no, you couldn't order stuff. Or rather, you could order it, but it would never arrive because any time somebody went to check your details, the "address" field would be mysteriously blank. The secret is hidden from *all*, not just from a specific person.

If the secret happens to be something to do with your location, but *not* your exact address, then you could order stuff and have it delivered, but the likes of Voldy still wouldn't be able to know where you are without the Secret Keeper. That's how powerful the Fidelius Charm is.

Comment: Imagine opening the door to "Voldemort the delivery guy" in like a baseball cap and everything XD "Package for a Mr... 'Father-of-the-boy-I'm-here-to-kill' "?

Comment: Also, now we know the real reason Voldy came back without his nose. So he could sneak up to sitting room windows and get around Fidelius Charms.

Comment: I disagree.  The workers at Amazon (or whatever) will read the shipping address, understand that it's the shipping address, ship the order to the shipping address, and the idea that you actually live there will slip from their brains.  People seeing that you have stuff shipped there will assume that you pick stuff up there, but don't live there.

Comment: And that's probably a good thing too, because otherwise the Dark Lord or a liege of his would pose as the delivery person. TVTROPES WARNING: tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DeliveryGuyInfiltration .  See also https://stickman.qntm.org/comics.php?n=511 and http://www.galactanet.com/comic/view.php?strip=133 .

Answer (score 2):

### Muggle post? 100% no go to your house, look into a P.O. Box or a friendly wizard neighbor.

Good news is, for the tech savvy Wizards companies of the 21st century, Owl post does not appear to be blocked by the Fidelius Charm.

Hedwig, the Daily Prophet, Hogwarts letters,  as well as letters written to the Potters all appeared to bypass the Fidelius Charm for delivery.

> ‘Hedwig!’ The snowy owl clicked her beak and nibbled his ear affection- ately as Harry stroked her feathers.
>
> ‘She’s been in a right state,’ said Ron. ‘Pecked us half to death when
>   she brought your last letters, look at this –’ He showed Harry the
>   index finger of his right hand, which sported a half-healed but
>   clearly deep cut. ‘Oh, yeah,’ Harry said. ‘Sorry about that, but I
>   wanted answers, you know –’
>
> ‘We wanted to give them to you, mate,’ said Ron. ‘Hermione was going
>   spare, she kept saying you’d do something stupid if you were stuck all
>   on your own without news, but Dumbledore made us-’
>
> ‘– swear not to tell me,’ said Harry.

Hedwig has been delivering letters to Grimmauld Place for weeks before Harry is given the secret.

Comment: Hm, makes you wonder why Voldy didn't just send an owl with some kind of cursed letter / parcel or something.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo dont think thats quite his style.

Comment: Voldemort: Incapable of Love _and_ common sense.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo If only he'd just owled a hand grenade to everyone in the Order...